# how to change background color of a link,when its related page is shown

Tags: css

As i said in title, how i can change background color of a link,when its related page is shown?

i have a side menu, using list and css:

```
<div id="liteMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i need to change bgColor of each link, when user naviagted to its related page.

thanks.

EDIT:
maybe i should to use jQuery and css.

Comment: Are you using a server-side language such as PHP? It would be better to add a class to the `<li>`. Unfortunately, there is no CSS selector for `:current` or similar.

Comment: you can't do it using CSS only (*given the HTML you provided*).

Comment: I use ASP.NET. I've been seen some sites when user click one of the menu items and navigate to its related page, the menu format will be change.

Comment: @MazdakShojaie How are you performing navigation?  Postback?  AJAX?

Comment: @Joe: I only use HREF attribute.

Comment: @MazdakShojaie You can accomplish this type of navigation using the `href` attribute but you will need javascript on the page to detect what page is being viewed and set the background color of the correct navigation item.  If you choose to do it this way, you should add IDs or classes to your list items.

Comment: You should to add a CSS class to your related menu item called "active" or something like that, then on your selector #liteMenu ul li a.active{background-color:Green}

Answer (score 0):

You can whatever style you want on the visited link.. check out w3c: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

So.. it's like this:

```
a:visited
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

And more options:

```
a:link    {color:green;}
a:visited {color:green;}
a:hover   {color:red;}
a:active  {color:yellow;}
```

Comment: It's not change the bgColor, after navigation

Comment: did you refresh your page? are you sure there are no other styles applied? are you using icognito? is your history enabled?

Answer (score 0):

you could always do this

```
<div id="liteMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a class="profile" href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li><a class="password" href="#">Change Password</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

then in the actual html of the page do this

```
<style>
 .dashboard { color:red;}
</style>
```

do that for each of the pages